# How to show one row in DataTable with DropdowndownButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

In Flutter, I am trying to have only ONE row with columns and if I change the last name with DropdownButton choices, change the first name column.

Instead of:

[image]

I would like:

[image]

### Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Rudd"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "Wilson"),
      User(firstName: "Jonah", lastName: "Hill"),
    ];
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Data Table Flutter Demo";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<User> users;
  List<User> selectedUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    selectedUser = List.from(users);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('DropdownButton in DataTable'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: DataTable(
            columns: [
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is First Name",
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text("LAST NAME"),
                numeric: false,
                tooltip: "This is Last Name",
              ),
            ],
            rows: selectedUser.asMap().entries.map((user) {
              int idx = user.key;
              print(idx);
              return DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(selectedUser[idx].firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${selectedUser[idx].firstName}');
                  },
                ),
                DataCell(DropdownButton<User>(
                  value: selectedUser[idx],
                  onChanged: (User newUser) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedUser[idx] = newUser;
                    });
                  },
                  items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value.lastName),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ))
              ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

[image]

Changes:

1. In the state of the StatefulWidget, I keep a `User selectedUser` instead of a `List<User> selectedUser`
2. I just create on `DataRow` for the `selectedUser`

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: DataTableDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName});

  static List<User> getUsers() {
    return <User>[
      User(firstName: "Paul", lastName: "Rudd"),
      User(firstName: "Owen", lastName: "Wilson"),
      User(firstName: "Jonah", lastName: "Hill"),
    ];
  }
}

class DataTableDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  DataTableDemo() : super();

  final String title = "Data Table Flutter Demo";

  @override
  DataTableDemoState createState() => DataTableDemoState();
}

class DataTableDemoState extends State<DataTableDemo> {
  List<User> users;
  User selectedUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    users = User.getUsers();
    selectedUser = users.first;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('DropdownButton in DataTable'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: DataTable(
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("FIRST NAME"),
              numeric: false,
              tooltip: "This is First Name",
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text("LAST NAME"),
              numeric: false,
              tooltip: "This is Last Name",
            ),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  Text(selectedUser.firstName),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Selected firstName: ${selectedUser.firstName}');
                  },
                ),
                DataCell(
                  DropdownButton<User>(
                    value: selectedUser,
                    onChanged: (User newUser) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedUser = newUser;
                      });
                    },
                    items: users.map<DropdownMenuItem<User>>((User value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<User>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value.lastName),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```